# restructure json data into a same structure , by removing unwanted data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is my JSON Data using Mongo :**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5f489968a26b303c54d0a174",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "SubCategory": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f5f3827c8f0c718c01428d2",
                    "name": "55",
                    "Brand": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f607898fea6362dc4eeaa5e",
                            "name": "sub category test2",
                            "Offer": []
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f6078a4fea6362dc4eeaa5f",
                            "name": "brand2",
                            "Offer": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f63839a1f7f3f2ec01cb19d",
                                    "title": "qsw",
                                    "Likes": [],
                                    "Comments": [],
                                    "Shares": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f686deb08a1272b003aa3c7",
                            "name": "Marvel",
                            "Offer": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f69ad691af8e2202447432c",
                                    "title": "Marvel offer",
                                    "Likes": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6af7a3bb67241d881c3d0b",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:18:14.073Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6af7afbb67241d881c3d0c",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:18:14.073Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Comments": [],
                                    "Shares": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f69b124d1c0f13b806ea20d",
                                    "title": "Marvel offer2",
                                    "Likes": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6af7c5bb67241d881c3d0d",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:18:14.073Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6af7cabb67241d881c3d0e",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:18:14.073Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Comments": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6af7d5bb67241d881c3d0f",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:31:36.930Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Shares": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f4899c2a26b303c54d0a175",
            "name": "Computer",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f489ba4ce0bd10c2c7af0eb",
            "name": "Clothing",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f48ab999579ac3690cd6897",
            "name": "abc",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f4c9c2b4630711ae099cec3",
            "name": "abcd",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f4cb13dc7fd2024ec020269",
            "name": "Kitchen",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e258a54fc924e02b0152",
            "name": "q",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e2bea54fc924e02b0153",
            "name": "qq",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e345a54fc924e02b0154",
            "name": "w",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e361a54fc924e02b0155",
            "name": "s",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e37ca54fc924e02b0156",
            "name": "Amitesh Category1",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e506848bf9451cf4f32f",
            "name": "laptop6",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59e5fba5ea37295c6b5f8b",
            "name": "Electronic2",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59fa26b4c9893a5ca5e96f",
            "name": "Electronic3",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59fa33b4c9893a5ca5e970",
            "name": "Electronic4",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59fa48b4c9893a5ca5e971",
            "name": "laptop",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59faaeb4c9893a5ca5e973",
            "name": "amitesh c1",
            "SubCategory": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f5f68e563d63905b093ebca",
                    "name": "sub cat 1",
                    "Brand": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59fceeb4c9893a5ca5e976",
            "name": "11",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f59ffa1b4c9893a5ca5e977",
            "name": "ccw",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5b7e1bab9a593bd6950aed",
            "name": "test 1",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5b870b3d722c41cc2e5f2f",
            "name": "qq wqwq wq",
            "SubCategory": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f5f680b578fea0b640fb754",
                    "name": "sub cat 2",
                    "Brand": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5b88033d722c41cc2e5f30",
            "name": "cvcv",
            "SubCategory": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f5f384ac8f0c718c01428d3",
                    "name": "sub cat 4",
                    "Brand": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f6078bafea6362dc4eeaa60",
                            "name": "brand2",
                            "Offer": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f687de408a1272b003aa3c8",
                                    "title": "Testing expire1 depndent1",
                                    "Likes": [],
                                    "Comments": [],
                                    "Shares": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f6078bffea6362dc4eeaa61",
                            "name": "brand3",
                            "Offer": []
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f6078c2fea6362dc4eeaa62",
                            "name": "brand4",
                            "Offer": []
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f6086c8fea6362dc4eeaa63",
                            "name": "brand 5",
                            "Offer": []
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f608712fea6362dc4eeaa64",
                            "name": "xyz 5",
                            "Offer": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f644628129ad62d301b4ca7",
                                    "title": "Testing expire11",
                                    "Likes": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f50963ad4e7b82584f29718",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:18:14.073Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f50993117bdf8161875e534",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:21:08.659Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f5099770c5b262edcbc34f0",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T07:33:16.483Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Comments": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f50913a7480733a1cfb90d3",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f646ff7e9df61290c73369f",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f646fffe9df61290c7336a0",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f647008e9df61290c7336a1",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f64700fe9df61290c7336a2",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f647103e9df61290c7336a6",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:46:18.010Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Shares": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f61ea593a89c23ff074cc2f",
                            "name": "aaaaaa",
                            "Offer": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "5f6330505c9ff214f8ed1bf1",
                                    "title": "12",
                                    "Likes": [],
                                    "Comments": [
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f508c55e0caf427404addea",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:31:36.930Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f647015e9df61290c7336a3",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:31:36.930Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f647079e9df61290c7336a4",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:31:36.930Z"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "_id": "5f6470bfe9df61290c7336a5",
                                            "updatedAt": "2020-09-03T06:31:36.930Z"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Shares": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5f69f5564e033228a41ed3fa",
                            "name": "Amitesh Kumar",
                            "Offer": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f5f5cf2578fea0b640fb753",
                    "name": "sub cat 3",
                    "Brand": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5f61f3d62565d12a0c101c59",
                            "name": "qq",
                            "Offer": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5f7f528147c330a46b5ae5",
            "name": "aa",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5f7f778147c330a46b5ae6",
            "name": "qwerer",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5f7f848147c330a46b5ae7",
            "name": "sasas",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f5f7fa98147c330a46b5ae8",
            "name": "a",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f6071e352a7f61230cd77ad",
            "name": "qw",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f60727f52a7f61230cd77ae",
            "name": "qqqq qq",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f60cd856eaac2316cd66ce7",
            "name": "Amitesh cat",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f61bd9daffdaa06543a1102",
            "name": "aaa",
            "SubCategory": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f63588f379ffc2e50a5f90a",
            "name": "aa ewew wew",
            "SubCategory": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query For This Data is :**

```
categoryModel.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    'from': subcategoryModel.collection.name,
                    "let": { "categoryId": "$_id" },
                    "pipeline": [
                        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$category", "$$categoryId"] } } },
                        { '$project': { 'name': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                        { '$match': req.body.subCategory ? { '_id': ObjectId(req.body.subCategory) } : {} },
                        {
                            "$lookup": {
                                "from": BrandModel.collection.name,
                                "let": { "subCategoryId": "$_id" },
                                "pipeline": [
                                    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$subCategory", "$$subCategoryId"] } } },
                                    { '$project': { 'name': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                                    { '$match': req.body.brand ? { '_id': ObjectId(req.body.brand) } : {} },
                                    {
                                        "$lookup": {
                                            "from": offerModel.collection.name,
                                            "let": { "brandId": "$_id" },
                                            "pipeline": [
                                                {
                                                    "$match": {
                                                        "$expr": {
                                                            "$eq": ["$brand", "$$brandId"],
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                { '$project': { 'title': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                                                { '$match': req.body.offer ? { '_id': ObjectId(req.body.offer) } : {} },
                                                {
                                                    "$lookup": {
                                                        "from": likeModel.collection.name,
                                                        "let": { "offerId": "$_id" },
                                                        "pipeline": [
                                                            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$offer", "$$offerId"] } } },
                                                            { '$project': { 'updatedAt': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                                                            {
                                                                '$match': req.body.from && req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                        "$lte": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.from ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$lt": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : {}
                                                            },
                                                        ],
                                                        "as": "Likes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "$lookup": {
                                                        "from": CommentModel.collection.name,
                                                        "let": { "offerId": "$_id" },
                                                        "pipeline": [
                                                            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$offer", "$$offerId"] } } },
                                                            { '$project': { 'updatedAt': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                                                            {
                                                                '$match': req.body.from && req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                        "$lte": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.from ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$lt": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : {}
                                                            },
                                                        ],
                                                        "as": "Comments"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "$lookup": {
                                                        "from": ShareModel.collection.name,
                                                        "let": { "offerId": "$_id" },
                                                        "pipeline": [
                                                            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$offer", "$$offerId"] } } },
                                                            { '$project': { 'updatedAt': 1, '_id': 1 } },
                                                            {
                                                                '$match': req.body.from && req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                        "$lte": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.from ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$gte": new Date(req.body.from),
                                                                    }
                                                                } : req.body.to ? {
                                                                    'updatedAt': {
                                                                        "$lt": new Date(req.body.to)
                                                                    }
                                                                } : {}
                                                            },
                                                        ],
                                                        "as": "Shares"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "as": "Offer"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "as": "Brand"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    'as': 'SubCategory',
                },
            },

            {
                $project:
                {
                    _id: 1,
                    name: 1,
                    SubCategory: 1
                }
            },
            //  { $unwind: '$Brand' },
            { $match: match },
            //  { $sort: sort },
            // { $limit: pagination.perPage },
            //{ $skip: pagination.skip },

        ])
```

What I need is, Only those record who have Offers, with its category and subCategory , I need offers like share comment as well , I search on google I tried many thing I reach to above code but I am stuck now. I am new in MongoDb , Even I tried to  restructuring the Result of mongoQuery but got stuck any Ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you match your output with:

```
{ $match: { "SubCategory.Brand.Offer": {"$exists": true} }
```

This should return only documents the have a Brand and an Offer.
You can check here: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-zEi5WkpgKF)

EDIT: to remove also the Offers that are empty, please check this option here:
[mongoplayground_2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2iJm5w_tU2E)

Comment: yes offers as well, thanks for your answer it helps me.

Comment: I edited the answer with the option to remove empty offers. Please upvote/accept the response if it was useful.